# API.AI - Is it possible to set the target intent before sending API.AI request?

Tags: sdk, dialogflow-es

I am building a mobile app to fill out a form. Basically, the app consists of many screens and every screen has the capability of being filled out by voice using API.AI SDK. So since all the screens may have similar attributes/fields types such as salary, amount, names, YES/NO questions, monthly expenses, rent amount, the API response is very inaccurate; it sometimes mixes an intent that is supposed to be for a different screen -It mixes the intents.

So my question is.. Can I set/configure a request by screen with the target intent? Example:

FINANCIAL INTENT - FINANCIAL SCREEN
1000 - Salary (API.AI is expecting only the value)
200 - Extra Incomes (API.AI is expecting only the value)

EXPENSES INTENT - EXPENSES INTENT 
200 - Rent (API.AI is expecting only the value) 
400 - Bills (API.AI is expecting only the value)

So, from my code can I set the target intent like financial intent or something like that so the agent does not get confused due to similar data types?

Thanks for your time and always willingness to help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use contexts.

API.AI contexts allows you to specify in which case (context) an Intent can be triggered.

With a form such as:

- > What is your name ?
- > What is your salary ?
- > What are your expenses ?

You can guide your user by setting for every Intent a context in and a context out:

- Name Intent:

  - context in: askedname
  - context out: askedsalary
- Salary Intent:

  - context in: askedsalary
  - context out: askedExpenses
- Expenses Intent:

  - context in: askedExpenses
  - context out: ...

This way, you ensure that the Name Intent won't be triggered until there is the `askedname` context, that the Salary Intent won't be triggered until there is the `askedsalary` context, etc.

You can find more explanations here: https://api.ai/docs/dialogs#non-linear_dialogs

Comment: Hi Maniae, thanks so much for your response. Yes, I figured out the solution could be using context. I thought API.AI could have an easier solution to implement this.